# Is the true nature of Brahman, Saguna or Nirguna?

Tags: philosophy, brahman

Brahman is said to be amorphous in nature. Apart from the main question in the title, here is a sub-query:

Can we keep away from Brahman after seeing or realizing it?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: Brahman is Saguna as well as Nirguna. To a Bhakta, He is Saguna, To a Jnani He is Nirguna, To a Karmite, He is neither Saguna nor Nirguna. What do you mean by 'It is amorphous in nature but can we avoid it'. :)

Comment: Reopening Q. Not sure why so many downvotes. To me the Q is clear. The true/absolute nature of *BrahM* (*Brahman*) is *Nirguna (Shunyata/Atma)*. Krishna describes this as *Avyakta* (BG 8.20). *Saguna BrahM* is an analogy of that *Avyakta*. For example: "For example". If I have never seen "water", then describing it will not make sense. So you may explain me as: "which flows", "which is coolant", "which is transparent", ...! All these descriptions collectively describe "water", but still not sufficient individually. Similarly, *Saguna BrahM* in various forms "try to" describe *"Nirguna BrahM"*.

Comment: @iammilind The part that everyone is confused by the "how can we avoid it" part.

Comment: What is meant by 'true/absolute' nature ? As a human being, If I'm awake 2/3rds of the day and asleep for 1/3rd, is my 'true' nature to be awake or to be asleep ? If I'm awake for 1/2 and asleep for 1/2, then ? During pralaya, his nirguna-tvam is displayed (from perspective of samsaris, not muktas), during shrishti/stithi/samharam his saguna-tvam is displayed, and they're both for equal times. He has ability to be both and uses both abilities when he wants. I feel it is like asking if the true nature of earth is to be in daytime or nighttime.

Comment: Brahma Sutra accepts both form of Brahman that means Brahman is Saguna as well as Nirguna. Also note that actually Brahman is also beyond them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Brahma**

The creative principle of the universe is called Brahma in Sanskrit. Brahma, who is depicted as emerging from the navel lotus of Narayana, is a metaphor for all of creation: its laws, its inherent intelligence, and its consciously manifested potencies which operate as sages, saints, rishis, devas, celestials, and divine beings of all kinds of nature, temperament and description. Narayana is the Sanskrit name given in the Upanishads to that which is the sum and substance of all the manifested and unmanifested realms. Narayana is that which is neither created nor destroyed but transcends the creation, life and destruction of the universe. Brahma creates, operates in the form of this universe for trillions of years, then dissolves back into Narayana. Narayana, however, is neither created nor destroyed. Later, another Brahma appears to begin the process again.

Since the term "Brahma" does not appear in the Vedas, its creation stems from the Sanskrit word "Brih" which means "'to grow" or "to expand." In this way, it became synonymous with Hiranyagharba: The Golden Egg of Creation. Growing from the Navel Lotus of Narayana, Brahma is the name for the principle which creates all of the manifest realms. Since the Vedas proclaim in the Purusha Suktam that "three quarters of this universe are in indestructible realms above," then clearly Brahma, with his finite duration, is connected to the realms of the universe which we inhabit which are subject to creation and dissolution.

Brahma was endowed with his "spouse" (Saraswati) and consciousness at the time of creation. Brahma made certain "beings" solely by the power of his mind and thought. These beings are called the mind-born sons of Brahma. The state of their consciousness is summarized by the title Brahma Rishi: Seer with the Understanding of Brahma. Brahma Rishis, in turn, can confer this state of consciousness upon others who prove themselves capable and worthy. For an example of the conferring of the state of Brahma Rishi upon one being by another, see the Story of Vishwamitra in the Chapter on the Gayatri Mantra.

To further understand the concept of Brahma and his relation to the universe as we know it, it is helpful to view the cosmos through the lens of the Vedic descriptions of the life of the universe as interpreted in human years. Here are cycles of time as recorded in the Vedas and Upanishads.
[Click here](http://veda.wikidot.com/brahma)

**Saguna and Nirgun**

NIRGUNA is the eternal all-pervading and omnipresent divine consciousness.
SAGUNA is the manifestation of God in form.

The sun is a graphic simile for this. Sunlight is the Nirguna form of the sun, and the celestial body is the Saguna form.

When God manifests in form he appears to be limited by his form, but his presence is unlimited and all-pervading. Nothing exists without God’s presence. God is omnipresent and absolute.

God is in everything, and everything is in God. God exists in everything that we call “good” as well as in everything we describe as “bad”. In God there is no limitation or differentiation, only unity. Nirguna God is pure energy, the living and conscious power that is at work in the Universe. Reality, the Supreme Self, is Nirguna God.
[Click here](http://www.chakras.net/yoga-principles/21-nirguna-and-saguna)

Answer (score -1):

Brahma is name of one of 3 Shakti (god) Brahma, Vishnu and Mahesh. Brahma is also known as Creator. He is responsible for creation/Birth/Formation of everything on Universe.
Shagun means good things/ Good sign/ Positive Symbol.
Nirgun means Bad Qualities/ negative qualities inside human being, the qualities which are responsible for destruction of mankind/human body also known as Durgun.

Comment: nirgun does not mean durgun. nirgun means no qualities. durgun means bad qualities.